# AutoComplete with vectors - android

Tags: android

I've have a Vector like this in my app:

```
  Vector<Firm> firmVector= new Vector<Firm>();
```

As you may see, this is a vector of objects from my own class `Firm`

So to my question, is it possible to add a `AutoComplete` to this `Vector?

Like this one, from [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_country);
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES);
  textView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Yes it is possible, I would search for a tutorial on making a custom adapter.

Comment: I already got a custom adapter, but my google search didnt result in any good tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it by implementing an ArrayAdapter, but you'll need to implement the `getFilter()` which is used by the `AutoCompleteTextView`. Something similar to this might work:

```
    private class FirmAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Firm> {
private Filter filter;
        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() 
        {
            if(filter == null){
                filter = new Filter(){
                    int lastlen = 0;
                    boolean initialized = false;

                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    @Override
                    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results)
                    {
                        filteredItems = (List<Firm>)results.values;
                        ArrayAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint)
                    {
                        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                        if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0){
                            results.values = null;
                        }else{
                            String val;
                            Firm obj;
                            constraint = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
                            int newlen = constraint.length();
                            LinkedList<Firm> filteredResults = new LinkedList<Firm>();
                            if(newlen < lastlen){
                                int i = 0, size = ArrayAdapter.super.getCount();
                                for(i=0;i<size;i++){
                                    obj = ArrayAdapter.super.getItem(i);
                                    val = obj.toString(); // CUSTOMIZE THIS
                                    if(val.contains(constraint)) filteredResults.add(obj);
                                }
                            }else{
                                int i = 0, size = getCount();
                                for(i=0;i<size;i++){
                                    obj = getItem(i);
                                    val = obj.toString(); // CUSTOMIZE THIS
                                    if(val.contains(constraint)) filteredResults.add(obj);
                                }
                            }
                            lastlen = newlen;
                            results.values = filteredResults;
                        }
                        return results;
                    }
                };
            }
            return filter;
        }
    }
}
```

I ripped this out of a project I have, so it will need some testing and cleanup to get working (in my case I have a Filter on a set of `JSONObject` instances, where you have a `Firm`) but try something like that. The comments with `CUSTOMIZE THIS` are where you want to actually perform the test based on the input into the `AutoCompleteTextView`.